# Remove override annotation even though JDK Compliance has been set to 1.6

Tags: android, annotations, overriding, java-6

I have annoying problem with this override annotation, I have come to google to find a solution but I can't find any clue. I have set the JDK Compliance to 1.6 it has a default, but eclipse still ask me to remove the override, what should I do to overcome this thing?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
public class HelloList extends Activity {
ListView list;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_list);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] values = new String[]{"StudentSite", "Staffsite", "BAAK", "Seminar"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There's two overrides in your code, which one is the IDE complaining about?

Comment: The error place in the `list.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: Could be a problem with your imports, I don't see any valid for OnItemClickListener.

Comment: Are you sure your project doesn't have its own setting?

Comment: @Perception Should be like this? `import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;` ?

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto - that would be correct.

Comment: did you tried with javacompiler as 1.7 ?

Comment: Yes i do, it will do nothing with the code and raise this error on the console windows `[2013-01-07 12:08:32 - HelloList] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.`

Answer (score 0):

Try it to set the SDK to 1.7 version,then it will not ask u to remove the override

Steps are:

1. Select the Project.
2. Right click,select the properties.
3. Select java compiler.
   set the value to 1.7 and clean the project from menu bar in project tab.

Comment: Ok Did u tried the android tools in right click of project, click the Fix project properties then clean the project then check java compiler